# Oscillating value of reset pin

Tags: stm32, reset

I have a custom board STM32WB55CGU6 with a reset pin connected to a pull-up resistor and a capacitor as shown in the schematic and PCB layout below (connected to the reset pin 7):

[image]
[image]

Using an oscilloscope, I obtained the following signal below between the resistor and capacitor of the reset as well as VCC:
[image]

Normally, from what I understand I am supposed to obtain a value of 3.3V at this point. I think that there is a problem with the capacitor but using a multimeter, I am able to obtain a value close to the actual value of the capacitor. Any other ideas on why I would have this?

UPDATE: After removing the pull up resistor as recommended, the signal remains the same.

Also, here is the full schematics. Please note that for the moment I have modified it slightly, changing the pins of PA13, PA14 to SWDIO and SWCLK respectively to test the PCB using a ST-Link V2.[image]

In addition to this, I have weird signals in my SWCLK and SWDIO pins.

Comment: I've no time to write a proper answer but... Your 100K resistor may be too high considering the input current of the pin is maybe 0.6..2 uA. With the slow rise time of your RC circuit, the change in input current may cause the oscillations you see. In short, replace the 100K with (say) 10K or put 10K in parallel with the 100K then try again and edit your findings into your question.

Comment: The STM32 does not need an external resistance. It is not even recommended to put an external resistance there under normal circumstances.

Comment: Please measure Vcc with your other oscilloscope channel.

Comment: @winny The Vcc is as provided by a voltage regulator at 3.3V.

Comment: @jellybean:  It is entirely possible for the output of a regulator to oscillate.

Comment: Post the whole schematics. Are all VCC and GND supplies properly connected? Including the core voltage section? Do you use internal SMPS or LDO? External supply? Are all boards like this or just one?

Comment: Didn't have time to check datasheets, too busy (still am). Please can you post the full schematic, as others have asked, or the part showing the MCU and its power supplies if the whole thing's too big or confidential.

Comment: Please show it on the same oscillogram as the RESET pin.

Comment: I'd suspect wrong value on the decoupling cap. If you use the wrong one on /reset, the MCU will go bananas. Maybe it's accidentally 100uF or something like that?

Comment: @Justme All the VCC and GND supplies are correctly connected and I am using SMPS.

Comment: @Lundin the value of the decoupling cap is good as I have measured it with a multimeter beforehand

Comment: Your oscillation is reasonably slow - 200Hz, which does seem about the right sort of speed for a power supply issue. There may be some fast spikes on the power lines that are just not visible on the 'scope. Make sure you are looking at the power on the micro itself ( or as close as you can ), and see if there is anything happening there with a faster time base. Take a look at VDDA as well as VDD. With the circuit powered down, measure the resistance between the GND 'earth' of the micro and the power supply

Comment: The new full schematics are downsampled to be almost illegible. Put more higher res picture please. Your edit suggests you see this ramp on VCC too, so it must be your power supply acting up.

Comment: What's the number 1 thing you do when you get a new board? You measure the voltage supply with a scope. I assumed this goes without saying.

Comment: @Lundin Exactly. Except step number 0 is to check and measure if there are any signs of problems even before applying power. There might be shorts, the board manufacturer may have accidentally used 10R resistors in place of 10k resistors, and if that controls regulator output voltage, something will blow up. Chanses of accidents are quite high if you are given a board designed by someone else, so it's best to verify the schematics first before applying power.

Comment: @Justme Naah, and current limit power supplies are for cowards :) I get street cred each time I show off the remains of tantalum caps that are stuck to the ceiling in my office :)

Comment: Im powering it up via Micro USB now and with that there are some spikes in the voltage. But will that greatly affect all the signals in the PCB?

Answer (score 3):

The STM32 has internal pull-up resistor (actually not a simple resistor). As you can see in this picture from STM32WB55CGU6 datasheet here is a preferred schematic for NRST:

[image: Fig 28 from datasheet]

Maybe the STM32 tries to control this R_pu with a MOSFET to check reset state (charge and discharge it,) so what you can do is simply remove your resistor and check if the problem goes away.

Again: you don't need an external resistor.

Comment: I'll check out this solution and see if it works! I know that it is not needed but I placed it there because I followed the schematic of the evaluation kit P-NUCLEO WB55

Comment: The pull-up resistance is a simple resistor, nothing more. The datasheet says it right above the figure 28, that the pull-up resistance is a true resistance. Furhter above that, on previous page, it also says the nRST pin pull-up is permanently connected.

Comment: I have edited the post with the recommended suggestions but no change to it

Comment: It's common practice to use external, relatively low ohm pull-ups on /reset, for applications with tough EMC requirements. Since the internal one will have a very high value, though perhaps not as high as 100k.

Comment: It is. But on STMs, the capacitor keeps the voltage quite stable, and mentions of adding external pull-up has been removed years ago. The nRST pin is also bi-directional, so the resistance, if added, must be high enough not to overload the open-drain output. Any external resistance also makes the capacitor charge faster, so reset is shorter. It could be compensated by increasing the capacitance, but again, since it is bi-directional, the open-drain output is specified to discharge 100nF fast enough. The reset connection should be fine, it is made according to datasheet and eval board.

Comment: As @Justme mentioned, nRST is bi-directional and goes low in case of a reset event. Maybe STM32 resets itself periodically for some reason, like WDT? Relatively steep fall seen on the graph suggests that capacitor is drained by the open-drain output of nRST pin.